# Using scripts to restore database, error says backup set holds a backup of a database other than existing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I am writing a script to automate the process of restoring one database using the .bak file of another database. I am getting the error:

> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing
>   'add_BackupDev' database.

The answers I am finding online all appear to have a solution that involves completing the restore manually and not through a script, which is not an option for me.

This is my code. The variable @LastDatabaseRestore is passing in the appropriate file path for my .bak file.

```
RESTORE DATABASE add_BackupDev
FILE = N'FILENAME'
FROM DISK = @LastDatabaseRestore
WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE 'add_backupDev' TO 'R:\DATA\add_BackupDev.mdf',
MOVE 'add_BackupDev_log' TO 'L:\LOG\add_BackupDev.ldf',
NOUNLOAD,
REPLACE;
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too Long To Comment

Using the `WITH REPLACE` option (as you have listed) would overwrite the database with what ever database is contained within the backup. The reason you are getting that error in your script may be because you use the `FILE` option.

> The FILE options preceding the backup device name specify the logical
>   file names of the database files that are to be restored from the
>   backup set; for example, FILE = 'FILENAME'

The reason you are getting the error may be because the backup set isn't the first database backup in the media set. You need to add the correct number to the `FILE` option in the `WITH` clause.

```
....
WITH FILE = 1,  --this may not need to be 1
....
```

If you don't have to explicitly specify the file name, then drop both `FILE` options.

```
RESTORE DATABASE add_BackupDev
FROM DISK = @LastDatabaseRestore
WITH
MOVE 'add_backupDev' TO 'R:\DATA\add_BackupDev.mdf',
MOVE 'add_BackupDev_log' TO 'L:\LOG\add_BackupDev.ldf',
NOUNLOAD,
REPLACE;
GO
```

That should restore your database.

Comment: when I remove both file options, i get an error under the first MOVE option saying "incorrect syntax."

when i remove the FILE = N'FILENAME', it tells me that it's trying to replace the .mdf and .ldf files of the database my .bak file is created from, which really makes no sense to me.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add back the `WITH` clause. I just fixed that and it should work now. And yes, it would replace them with the ones from the .bak, since you are using `REPLACE`. The last code snippet should work now.

Comment: had some trouble getting the right file names for the move, but it works now! Thanks!

Comment: No worries at all! Remember you can rename them with MOVE as you MOVE them too.